# Merging together a lot of small queries

Tags: optimization, flask-sqlalchemy, micro-optimization

I am making an app that analyses in-game items of a player and displays their prices. Items are retrieved from outside in JSON format in form of an array of items, which have fields like id, and several other attributes that are to be processed. Each item is fully defined only after processing all the attributes. Accessing each item's price in SQLAlchemy takes microseconds (1-2), but there are several hundreds of them, so there is a couple second load time, which is not really acceptable delay for a web app. What ways are there to consolidate a query or otherwise speed up accessing the information?

Model is really simple:

```
    class Item(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = "prices"
        defindex = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        quality = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        craftable = db.Column(db.Boolean, primary_key=True)
        tradeable = db.Column(db.Boolean, primary_key=True)
        item_metadata = db.Column(db.String(70), primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(70), primary_key=True)
        currency = db.Column(db.String(70))
        price = db.Column(db.Float)
        price_high = db.Column(db.Float)
```

It is a set of attributes that constitute a primary key and price, no relationships, nothing special.

Comment: Can you describe the model(s) that are used to obtain the data for the item and its price? More specifically, does this data exist in a single table/model? Have you checked out the SQLAlchemy tutorial docs (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html), under "Selecting", "Operators", and "Conjunctions"? Many good examples there, let us know if one of those scenarios sounds close to your own.

Comment: @YellowShark added.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a little hazy on some important details though: you described having to make several hundred small queries - is this in your controller/view? It would be helpful to see some of that code, in order to help you devise an approach that consolidates them. Some points I'm interested in: how does this page know which items to query for? What are the conditions in your current queries? Is there a separate table that keeps track of the items that belong to a player? How does the page know which player to use?

Comment: @YellowShark added every important detail that I can think of.

Comment: OK, that's helpful for sure, I think I'm beginning to understand - so you're basically starting with some JSON data from someone's API or whatever; also, it's an array, and so you're iterating over it & and using each element of this array to then make a query to your own database. Let me think about a couple options for a little bit - I'm not sure I'll have a perfect answer, but I definitely think I understand the nature of your issue, thanks for explaining that a bit more.

Comment: Here's the approach I would pursue: take the JSON data and insert it into a temporary table, and then use that temporary table to left-join against your Items (the prices table). These are both relatively performant tasks, and could be done in 2 queries, versus hundreds+. At that point, once you've computed the data and the left-join, you could pickle/cache/store that data as one big blob, and delete the temporary table. That's what I would recommend. Leaving this as a comment since I'm not providing sample code using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @YellowShark thanks a lot for your suggestion, definitely an interesting idea. But the thing is that I am making this project as a website, so creating these temporary tables on-the-fly sounds cumbersome.